# How to change first column name in r

Tags: r

I have a simple question. Table imported in R always has row.names as first column name. How to change it to for example "id"? This is a simple example of my table
row.names name1 name2

I want to change row.names to id to get the following talbe
id name1 name2

Answer (score 3):

Your rows must have names or numbers. This is not a column in your table (see `row.names` under `?read.table` for more details). IF you try to set `row.names` to `NULL` it will force sequential numbering of rows. You can add an `id` column of sequential numbers for your rows like this:

```
table$id <- 1:nrow(table)
```

If you have specific `row.names` on your data that you want to preserve you can do this...

```
table$id <- rownames( table )
```

Then when you save the table to disk

```
write.table( table , "~/mytable.txt" , row.names = FALSE )
```

Note that when you read the table back in, R will create sequentially numbered row names. `data.frames` *MUST* have row names!

Comment: It seems this is a problem in R. This issue was discussed and a solution was suggested in link https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-August/077110.html

Comment: @user2545342 AFAIK it is not a problem in R. R behaves exactly as is documented. The link provided is not a *solution* to an R problem, it is a workaround for the OP to get their desired result. I'll update the answer for what I think you want.